# SyntaxHighlighter margin bug with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

**I have this code.**

```
<pre class="brush: xml">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;Test xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;&gt;
    &lt;ABC&gt;
      &lt;A&gt;B&lt;/A&gt;
    &lt;/ABC&gt;
&lt;/Test&gt;</pre>
```

**And this javascript.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
```

**Before that I loaded:**

- XRegExp.js
- shCore.js
- shBrushXml.js

**And the css:**

- shCoreRDark.css
- shThemeRDark.css

**But it looks like:**
[image: Bug example]

The problem is that the first line is between line 1 and 2. The margin issnt correct or something else!?
I dont know. With FireBug I cant find the problem :(

**And by the way**... Is it possible to disable/hide the "?" button on the top right corner?

Fiddle example (bad parsing!?): http://jsfiddle.net/Zrm2G/

Comment: We need to see your CSS. Ideally we need to see a working example of your page using JSFiddle or similar? Have you also tried inspecting the HTML/CSS yourself using firebug to see which CSS rules are being applied to the <pre> tag?

Comment: I prepare a JSFiddle example. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Its like http://jsfiddle.net/Zrm2G/

Comment: You can not link to the js files on GITHUB with jsFiddle

Answer (score 9):

I believe the issue has to do with the SyntaxHighlighter using class="container" which has a name collision with BootStrap.

In particular, bootstrap.css adds the following, which is putting the margin in before our displayable content:

```
.container:before, .container:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
```

I resolved this by overriding this css in my sites main css file when the container class is used within the SyntaxHighlighter table:

```
.syntaxhighlighter table .container:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in Dokuwiki and works like a charm. Added those lines to this file:
    `lib/plugins/syntaxhighlighter3/sxh3/styles/shCore.css`